# didReceiveRemoteNotification presentViewController from anywhere when running

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a `UIViewController` when a remote notification is received.

My code works to point, but when the app is running and the user is on any other than the first screen/navigation stack, the `UIViewController` isn't presented.

Can anyone help please? Note I want to keep the navigation bar when the `UIViewController` is presented

I get this warning when I try to present the 'UIViewController' elsewhere

**Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

Thanks in advance

Here is my code for `didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

  var payload = userInfo
  let requestID = payload["requestID"] as! String


  let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

  let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let vc : RequestViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RequestViewController") as! RequestViewController
    vc.requestID = requestID

  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

  rootViewController.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: How does the user enter a new navigation stack? (are you using a UITabBar for example?)

Comment: Nope no UITabBar, just a series of UINavigationControllers, the view presents, but on only the first stack only, so the initial view controller only

Comment: Editted question with warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing:

```
rootViewController.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to:

```
rootViewController.visibleViewController!.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```